# Compare if every element of a list is larger then every other elements

Tags: python, loops, compare

I want to compare if element one of a list is larger then every other element(same for every other element). 
If one element is larger than an other it gets a 1. The sum of 1s (depending on the number of comparison "won") should be store in a way that let me know how many comparison are wow for each specif element of the list.

To clarify every element to a list would be an individual with an ID

Python

```
#Here I create 10 random values which I call individual with the random
#funcion plus mean and standard deviation
a, b = 3, 10
mu, sigma = 5.6, 2
dist = stats.truncnorm((a - mu) / sigma, (b - mu) / sigma, loc=mu,  scale=sigma)
individuals = dist.rvs(10)

#Initialize the list where I want to store the 1s
outcome = num.zeros(n)

#Trying to loop through all the elements

for k in range(0, n):
    for j in range(0, n):
        if individuals[k] == individuals[j]:
            continue
        elif individuals[k] < individuals[j]:
            continue
        elif individuals[k] > individuals[j]:
             outcome[i] += 1

    return outcome[i]
```

I end up having an outcome with one single value.
Probably it summed up every 1s in the first element

Comment: Just sort the list, the index of the element in the sorted list is the number of elements that are less than it.

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You should habe placed a list of numbers and explain the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more efficient way, by sorting the list first, which makes the process O(n*log(n)) instead of O(n**2).

We sort the list, keeping the original index of each value (this is O(n*log(n)).

Then, we go once over the list to set the output counts, which are the indices of the values in the sorted list, except for the duplicates - in this case, we just keep track of the number of identical values to adjust the result.

```
def larger_than(values):
    ordered_values = sorted((value, index) for index, value in enumerate(values))

    out = [None] * len(values)

    # take care of equal values
    equals = 0
    prev = None
    for rank, (value, index) in enumerate(ordered_values):
        if value == prev:
            equals += 1
        else:
            equals = 0
            prev = value
        out[index] = rank - equals
    return out
```

Some test:

```
values = [1, 4, 3, 3, 10, 1, 5, 2, 7, 6]
print(larger_than(values))
# [0, 5, 3, 3, 9, 0, 6, 2, 8, 7]
```